# Make String input an object instance

Tags: java, variables, methods, java.util.scanner, instance

```
user1.subscribe();
```

user1 is under a User class, I'm looking at how to use Scanner to get the user input. So when asking username using Scanner, like user2, that can be used to call user2.subscribe();

Used Scanner String input but can't convert to object

```
User userID;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
userID = input.next();
```

Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to User

So the user has been added as follow

```
User user1 = new User("user1", "James Smith", "915661829");
```

In main method I can call user1.subscribe() to subscribe the user. I'm trying to ask for an input, like "user2" which will call user2.subscribe().

The Scanner would ask for the username of the user that wants to subscribe.

Comment: What do you mean with "user1 is under a User class"? The solution to your problem is anyway most likely to use a map as Map<String, User> where you map strings to the user instances.

Comment: You would collect information using `Scanner`. It can read `String`, `int`, etc. After collecting relevant information, you would instantiate a `User` with the correct information. A `User` is (presumably) not just a username.

Answer (score 0):

A Scanner's `next()` method will indeed only produce String values. If you want to create a new User instance, you would have to convert that String value to a User manually somehow.

Maybe User has a constructor that takes a name?

```
String username = input.next();
User userID = new User(username);
```

Comment: The user has already been created. I'm looking to see how I can convert a string to object if possible

Comment: So I assume you have some sort of `Collection` of users. You would need to define a way to _search_ for the correct user, and then call `.subscribe` if a user was found.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make field to accept input from command line. Something like this.

```
class User {
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And then accept input in the field, and you need to instantiate object before populating it.

```
User userID = new User();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
userID.setId(input.next());
System.out.println("User object : " + userID);
```